# Order of picklist fields in fieldset

Tags: fieldsets

I have a fieldset that I dynamically get the fields from & display on a form.  I am finding that the picklist fields consistently appear below the other fields on the form when I iterate through the fieldset fields.  I can't figure out how to change the order of where the picklist fields appear on the form.  I can change the order of the other field types by arranging them on the fieldset's page layout.  For example, if I have a picklist as the first field in the fieldset, it always appears at the end of the list of fields when I iterate through the fieldset.

Comment: The order in which a developer lists displayed fields determines their order of appearance on a Visualforce page.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  My code gets the fieldset & then iterates through the set to display the fields on the screen.  I am not manipulating the order during the iteration.  I can rearrange all the fields but the picklists by changing the field order on the fieldset page layout.  No matter where I put the picklists on the fieldset page layout, they always appear below the other field types.